# Why does powershell tolerate the absence of space between `cd` and `..`?

Tags: powershell

Why and how does `cd..` work, i.e., without a space between the command and the argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is an automatic function bundled with `powershell`.  You can discover the definition of commands by using `Get-Command`.  In this scenario:

```
PS /> Get-Command -Name cd..

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        cd..
```

And to get more detail:

```
PS /> Get-Command -Name cd.. | Format-List -Property * -Force

HelpUri             :
ScriptBlock         : Set-Location ..
CmdletBinding       : False
DefaultParameterSet :
Definition          : Set-Location ..
Options             : None
Description         :
Verb                :
Noun                :
HelpFile            : System.Management.Automation.dll-Help.xml
OutputType          : {}
Name                : cd..
CommandType         : Function
Source              :
Version             :
Visibility          : Public
ModuleName          :
Module              :
RemotingCapability  : PowerShell
Parameters          : {}
ParameterSets       : {}
```

In short, you can also access the definition of a function by using the `Function:` drive which will give you the `scriptblock` object of the function converted to a string for the console.

```
PS /> ${Function:cd..}
Set-Location ..
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I didn't expect the language to accept functions ending with dots. I tend to think these kinds of shortcuts remnant of older systems belong better to the alias set, but there might be a rationale for making it a function.

Comment: @JohanBoulé Question marks, quotes, and others are also valid characters as long as they're not the first character

Comment: @JohanBoulé: `cd..` cannot be defined as an alias, because in PowerShell aliases can only refer to other command _names_, not also their arguments. Therefore, since argument `..` must be passed to `Set-Location`, a function definition is necessary.